# want an example/illustration use of JS aggregates function in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, aggregates, interactive-grid

i saw the documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aexjs/model.html#.FieldMeta
and want to have an example of using "aggregates" function in IG / IR where it is possible and how to. please guide.

Answer (score 1):

For each column you want to use aggregates in a JavaScript Initialization Code
add:

```js
function(options) {
    options.defaultGridColumnOptions = {
        aggregates: ["SUM"] //or : "COUNT", "COUNT_DISTINCT", "AVG", "MIN", "MAX", "MEDIAN"
    };
    return options;
}
```

Comment: thanks @TonyS , 
is it possible i can reference this value to another region's "page item" to set its value or to calculate other value(s) ? if yes how i can do it? 
regards

Comment: hi @TonyS, on apex.oracle.com, simply created a page with IG (not editable), copy&paste your give code in SAL column's JavaScript Initialization Code, run it and it is showing error... nothing on page. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') . is there anything else i have to do for it? regards